# How to prioritize strpos to find me the most accurate result

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, strpos

I have an array:

```
$array_of_routes = ['users/', 'articles/more', 'users/get', 'homepage/'];
```

And, For example I have a string:

```
$route = "users/get/1";
```

So I tried to find it by using strpos but because 'users/' comes a head of 'users/get' in $array_of_routes I get the 'users/' in return and not the 'users/get', This is makes sense because that is what I asked the code to do.

But is there a way to priorotize or make the result more accurate when trying to find a substring in a string?

Note: when removing 'users/' from the array I get the 'users/get'

This is my code:

```
foreach($array_of_routes as $uri){
  if(strpos($current_uri, $uri) !== false)
    return $uri;

}
```

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: Sort the matches to longest first.

Comment: Are trailing slashes optional on your routes?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, it can be an option!

Comment: @user2561521 I see, please check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break apart the `$route` and match it with the highest specificity available in `$array_of_routes`

```
<?php
$array_of_routes = ['users', 'articles/more/', 'users/get', 'homepage'];
$route = "users/get/1/fgd/d/fg/";

// No reason to have trailing nor leading slashes or spaces; they are just noise
$array_of_routes = array_map(function($v){return trim(trim($v, '/'));}, $array_of_routes );
$route = trim(trim( $route, '/' ));

// Get the requested route pieces
$route_pieces = explode('/', $route);

// Make sure we loop enough times to account for all of the pieces
for($i = 0; $i<count($route_pieces); ++$i)
{
    // With each loop, build the route with one piece less and check if it exists in $array_of_routes
    if(in_array(implode('/', array_slice($route_pieces, 0, (count($route_pieces)-$i))), $array_of_routes))
    {
        echo 'Most specific route: '.implode('/', array_slice($route_pieces, 0, (count($route_pieces)-$i)));
        echo 'Arguments: '.implode('/', array_slice($route_pieces, (count($route_pieces)-$i)));
        break;
    }
}
```

Output for `$route = "users/get/1/fgd/d/fg/";`:

```
Most specific route: users/get
Arguments: 1/fgd/d/fg
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that

*2 routes A and B with the same string-prefix can be of the same level or different levels*

example 1) same level (prefix=`/users/`):

```
/users/get
/users/post
```

example 2) different levels (prefix=`/users`):

```
/users/get
/users
```

we can say that:

**Storing the routes in the 'longest-first' order**, you obtain this statement:
*2 routes with the same string-prefix and different levels are always stored with the more specific level first.*

How to obtain:

```
$array_of_routes = ['users/', 'articles/more', 'users/get', 'homepage/', ...];

function sort_by_length($a,$b){
  return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
}

usort($array_of_routes,'sort_by_length');

function findRoute($current_uri){
  foreach($array_of_routes as $uri){
    if(strpos($current_uri, $uri) === 0){
      return $uri;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the `strpos` function have to return 0, otherwise you can find some wrong routes matching your uri.

Answer (score -1):

Easy!
Sort your array so that users/get is in front of users/.  Do a `$array_of_routes = rsort($array_of_routes);`

this puts your longer matches first and if your longest item matches the function returns.